# How to configure Sails Controller to use only 'Post' method

Tags: sails.js

I saw that all controllers methods are free for GET and POST. How to ensure to permits only POST for some methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using [action blueprints](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api?q=blueprint-routes) to automatically route URLs to custom controller action, then those actions will respond to `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` and `PATCH` methods by default.  If you'd rather control which methods are allowed, you have a few choices:

1. Disable certain methods using custom routes in your [**config/routes.js**](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.routes.html) file.  For example, if you have a `foo` action in **UserController.js** that you don't want to allow `GET` requests for, you can add the following custom route:

   ```
   "GET /user/foo": {response: 'forbidden'}
   ```

   to automatically route it to the "forbidden" response (same as doing `res.forbidden()` in a controller)
2. Test `req.method` within the action itself, and return early for methods you don't want to process:

   ```
   if (req.method.toUpperCase() == 'GET') {return res.forbidden();}
   ```
3. Disable action routes by setting `actions` to `false` in your [**config/blueprints.js**](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.html) file.  You'll then have to set up all your routes manually in your [**config/routes.js**](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.routes.html) file.